# StackExchange.Redis Transaction chaining parameters

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

I'm trying to execute a basic transactional operation that contains two operations

1. Get the length of a set `scard MySet`
2. Pop the entire set with the given length : `spop MySet len`

I know it is possible to use `smembers` and `del` consecutively. But what I want to achieve is to get the output of the first operation and use it in the second operation and do it in a transaction. Here is what I tried so far:

```csharp
var transaction = this.cacheClient.Db1.Database.CreateTransaction();
var itemLength = transaction.SetLengthAsync(key).ContinueWith(async lengthTask =>
{
  var length = await lengthTask;
  try
  {
       // here I want to pass the length argument
       return await transaction.SetPopAsync(key, length); // probably here transaction is already committed
      // so it never passes this line and no exceptions thrown.
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
       throw;
  }

});

await transaction.ExecuteAsync();
```

Also, I tried the same thing with `CreateBatch` and get the same result. I'm currently using the workaround I mentioned above. I know it is also possible to evaluate a Lua script but I want to know is it possible with transactions or am I doing something terribly wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nature of redis is that you **cannot** read data during multi/exec - you only get results when the exec runs, which means it isn't possible to use those results *inside* the multi. What you are attempting is kinda doomed. There are two ways of doing what you want here:

1. Speculatively read what you need, then perform a multi/exec (transaction) block using that knowledge as a *constraint*, which SE.Redis will enforce inside a WATCH block; this is really complex and hard to get right, quite honestly
2. Use Lua, meaning: ScriptEvaluate[Async], where you can do everything you want in a series of operations that execute contiguously on the server without competing with other connections

Option 2 is almost always the right way to do this, ever since it became possible.

Comment: Thanks, I was suspicious about doing something unnatural now it is clarified.

Comment: This is also known as Optimistic locking mechanism.